# bllim / laravel4-datatables-package -> get the id from the query

Tags: laravel-4, datatables

I'm trying to get the ID from the query when I use edit_column but I get it only for the 'id' column, when I try to get it for the 'operations' column I get the html markup of the 'id' column.

Here is the code:

```
public function ajaxGetAllPages()
{
    $pages = Page::select(array('id','title','updated_at','status'));
    return Datatables::of($pages)
    ->edit_column('id', '<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes tooltips" value="{{ $id }}" data-placement="left" data-original-title="&nbsp;אינדקס # {{ $id }}&nbsp;" />')
    ->edit_column('title','<a href="{{ URL::route( \'admin.pages.index\') }}">{{ $title }}</a>')
    ->edit_column('updated_at', '{{ date("d-m-Y | H:i",strtotime($updated_at)) }}')
    ->edit_column('status', '{{ $status }}')
    ->edit_column('operations',
                    '<a href="#" data-id="{{ $id }}" class="btn btn-xs blue btn-editable tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="עריכה"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                     <a href="#" data-id="{{ $id }}" class="btn btn-xs dark btn-trash tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="לארכיון"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                     <a href="#" data-id="{{ $id }}" class="btn btn-xs red btn-removable tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="מחיקה"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                     <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">עוד <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">פעולה</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">פעולה</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>'
    )
    ->make();
}
```

Markup result - http://screencast.com/t/nIefrpqc8

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Thanks,
Chen

Answer (score 0):

According to `Bllim` docs:

`If you use double quotes while giving content of add_column or edit_column, you should escape variables with backslash () else you get error. For example:`

```
edit_column('id',"- {{ \$id }}")
```

Use backslash before $id.

```
->edit_column('operations',
                    '<a href="#" data-id="{{ \$id }}" class="btn btn-xs blue btn-editable tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="עריכה"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                     <a href="#" data-id="{{ \$id }}" class="btn btn-xs dark btn-trash tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="לארכיון"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                     <a href="#" data-id="{{ \$id }}" class="btn btn-xs red btn-removable tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="מחיקה"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                     <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">עוד <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">פעולה</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">פעולה</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>'
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error when I use it and data is not displayed. _DataTables warning (table id = 'datatable-ajax'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error._ :\